# “Edit comment” window add view all comments on post, how?

Tags: php

"Edit comment" window add view all comments on post, how?

Plugin or code?

In a graphic editor, I made an example (and more comment dates, they are not in the images)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sorry for my English

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the comment edit window, show all comments that refer to the post whose comment is being edited.